# Android: ListView not updates

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

My program consists of ViewPager with two pages. One of these pages has listview. ***onResume*** method then my application backs to foreground i want to refresh my list with fresh data by adding new items to the list.

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();       

        if(wasPaused) {             
            int currentPage = getCurrentItem();

            if(LIST_PAGE == currentPage) {
                final CustomListAdapter listAdapter = pageAdapter.getListAdapter();

                if(null != listAdapter && !listAdapter.isEmpty()) {
                    CustomObject last = listAdapter.getItem(0);
                    Long someLastValue = last.getDate();

                    final List<CustomObject> recentData = DataSource.getInstance(this).getList(someLastValue, null);

                    if(!recentData.isEmpty()) {
                        adapter.getListAdapter().addAll(recentCalls);
                        adapter.getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();            
                    }
                }           
            }
        }
    }
```

After ***onResume*** execution my listview doesn't update though there was new data and adapter increased after ***addAll*** method. What i'm doing wrong?

Edit: I have created custom ArrayAdapter for my list. Should i add to CustomArrayAdapter or the ArrayList of CustomArrayAdapter?

Comment: seems like increased your `listAdapter`, and not the `pageAdapter.getListAdapter()`. Check in debugger.

Comment: Edited code. Result is the same.

Comment: why are you running it in ruOnUiThread? As it seems to me it's already running in main (UI) thread. Try to remove these lines.

Comment: Changed code. ListView still doesn't updates.